# Find polynomials $f(x),g(x)$ such that $f(x)p(x) + g(x)q(x) = 2x^2 + 6x +2$

Tags: polynomials

Let $$p(x) = x^4 + 7x^3 + 14x^2 + 7x+1 $$$$q(x) = x^4 +10x^3 + 23x^2 + 10x+1$$

Find polynomials $f(x),g(x)$ with rational coefficients such that $$f(x)p(x) + g(x)q(x) = 2x^2 + 6x +2$$

I totally have no idea to solve this problem... Please help me to do it. Thank you!!

Comment: It reminds me of the sort of thing you would use the extended Euclidean algorithm for, to write a linear combination of two ordinary integers as some multiple of their GCD. Could you try something like that here?

Comment: First things first, what is $\gcd(p,q)?$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you factor both polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$ you'll get

$p(x) = (x^2+3x+1) (x^2+4x+1)$

$q(x) = (x^2+3x+1) (x^2+7x+1)$

These factors are irreducible (Why?).

Therefore $gcd(p,q) = x^2+3x+1$. Now with the Euclidean algorithm (or some guessing) you should be able to get two polynomials $r,s$ such that $$r(x^2+4 x+1)+s(x^2+7 x+1) = gcd(x^2+4 x+1,x^2+7 x+1) = 1$$

If you multiply this by $2(x^2+3x+1)$ you get exactly what you want:

$$(2r) p + (2s)q = 2x^2+6x+2.$$

Hint 1:

> $r,s$ are of degree 1

Hint 2:

> $x+7$,$x+4$

Comment: Why did you write Hint 1 Hint 2 but then leave the boxes empty?

Comment: @cpiegore, if I let the mouse rest on one of the hint boxes, I see something after a second. Not instantaneous.

Comment: @cpiegore These are spoiler tagged. Move your mouse over them and see what happens=)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grobner basis to solve this,

$f1=x^4+7x^3+14x^2+7x+1;$,

$f2=x^4+10x^3+23x^2+10x+1;$

$f3=(f2-f1)/3=x^2+3x^2+x$

$f4=-3(f2-(x+7)f3)=x^2+3x+1$

Since,
$2x^2+6x+2 = 2*f4$
Now just replace it as $f4->f3->f2$ till everything is in terms of $f1$ and  $f2$,

Answer:  $2/3(-(x+4)f2+(x+7)f1)$

Comment: Can you tell us more about those *Grobner cases*? I have never heard of this.

Comment: @flawr:sorry, I meant Grobner Basis.